# use RX to trigger events at varying times?

Tags: c#, multithreading, system.reactive

I've got a large collection of simple pair class:

```
public class Pair { public DateTime Timestamp; public double Value; }
```

They are sorted by the ascending Timestamp. I want to trigger an event with the Value (say, Action<double>) for each item in the list at the appropriate time. The times are in the past, so I need to normalize the Timestamps such that the first one in the list is "now". Can we set this up with the Reactive Extensions such that it triggers the next event after on the difference in time between two items?

Comment: Have you had a look at http://reactiveproperty.codeplex.com/ ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Say `pairs` is your sequence:

```
var obs = pairs.OrderBy(p => p.Timestamp).ToObservable();
```

Now `obs` is pairs as an ordered observable.

```
Observable.Zip(
    obs,
    obs.Take(1).Concat(obs),
    (pair1, pair2) => Observable.Timer(pair1.Timestamp - pair2.Timestamp)
      .Select(_ => pair1.Value))
.Concat()
.Subscribe(/* Do something here */);
```

The zip takes care of turning the absolute times into offsets. It will take the sequence and join it with itself, but offset by one, as follows

```
Original 1--2--4--7--11
Offset   1--1--2--4--7--11
Joined   0--1--2--3--4
```

This new value is then put into the `Observable.Timer` to delay it the appropriate amount. The final `Concat` flattens the result from an `IObservable<IObservable<double>>` into an `IObservable<double>`. This assumes that your sequence is ordered.

Comment: Nice solution. I'd add `var orderedObs = pairs.OrderBy(p => p.Timestamp).ToObservable()` to make it obvious what needs to happen and use that instead. I made these changes..

Comment: This helps a lot. I used it to query historical data and play it back like it was originally recorded. A simulator to prove the new system works.

Comment: Took me a while to figure out what exactly was going on, but I get it now. Rx is a mindf***. Awesome solution though. +1

Answer (score 2):

If by "using Rx" you allow me to just use the Rx schedulers, then this is a very easy solution:

```
Action<double> action =
    x =>
        Console.WriteLine(x);

var ts0 = pairs.Select(p => p.Timestamp).Min();

pairs
    .ForEach(p => 
        Scheduler
            .ThreadPool
            .Schedule(
                p.Timestamp.Subtract(ts0),
                () => action(p.Value)));
```

This uses the `System.Interactive` extension `ForEach`, but you could just use a regular `foreach` loop to load up the scheduler.

I've tested the code with the following dummy data:

```
var pairs = new []
{
    new Pair { Timestamp = new DateTime(2011, 1, 1, 7, 12, 30), Value = 1.1, },
    new Pair { Timestamp = new DateTime(2011, 1, 1, 7, 12, 45), Value = 1.2, },
    new Pair { Timestamp = new DateTime(2011, 1, 1, 7, 12, 40), Value = 1.3, },
};
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Does the scheduler have its own queue? Or would this code chew up the entire threadpool? I'm just worried about the scalability of this solution.

Comment: @Brannon - If I recall correctly schedulers use a heap sort internally to queue up the actions. Also a scheduler will only execute one action at a time and will reuse the current thread if another action is immediately ready to go. So they only ever use one thread at a time.

Answer (score 0):

I think this problem is interesting, this would be my first go at it.

```
static void RunPairs(IEnumerable<Pair> pairs, Action<double> pairEvent)
{
  if (pairs == null || !pairs.Any() || pairEvent == null)
    return;

  // if we can promise the pairs are already sorted
  // obviously we don't need this next line
  pairs = pairs.OrderBy(p => p.Timestamp);
  var first = pairs .First().Timestamp;
  var wrapped = pairs.Select(p => new { Offset = (p.Timestamp - first), Pair = p });

  var start = DateTime.Now;

  double interval = 250; // 1/4 second
  Timer timer = new Timer(interval);

  timer.AutoReset = true;
  timer.Elapsed += (sender, elapsedArgs) =>
  {
    var signalTime = elapsedArgs.SignalTime;
    var elapsedTime = (signalTime - start);

    var pairsToTrigger = wrapped.TakeWhile(wrap => elapsedTime > wrap.Offset).Select(w => w.Pair);
    wrapped = wrapped.Skip(pairsToTrigger.Count());

    if (!wrapped.Any())
      timer.Stop();

    foreach (var pair in pairsToTrigger)
      pairEvent(pair.Value);    
  };

  timer.Start();
}
```

Comment: This is really needlessly complex given Rx has extensions such as `Timer`, `Defer` and `Delay`.

Comment: @yamen I've never used Rx, nor really plan to. I wanted to respond how to do it from scratch as a challenge because I thought it was intersting :) sorry if my answer in this context is merely spam.

Comment: No need to apologise, I hope you learn something from the Rx solutions above. Your answer actually serves as an example as to why Rx is great :-)